# Program to solve matrices only works sometimes

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that solves 3x4 matrices. It works sometimes, but often fails. Can someone help me out? I think it may be a problem in the array not wanting to story fractions/decimals, but I'm new to Python, so I could be completely wrong. Any help is truly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import numpy as np 
 A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,-1,-1,0],[4,-3,1,5]])
 W = np.empty([3,4])
 Z = np.empty([3,4])
 def solveMatricies(A):
    A[0] = (A[0] / A[0][0])
    A[1] = (A[1] - A[1][0]*A[0])
    A[2] = (A[2] - A[2][0]*A[0])
 

    A[1] = (A[1] / A[1][1]) 
    print(A)
    A[0] = (A[0] - A[0][1]*A[1])
    A[2] = (A[2] - A[2][1]*A[1])


    A[2] = (A[2] / A[2][2])
    A[0] = (A[0] - A[0][2]*A[2]) 
    A[1] = (A[1] - A[1][2]*A[2])
    print(A)

 if A[0][0] != 0:
    solveMatricies(A)
 elif A[1][0] != 0:
    W[0] = A[1]
    W[1] = A[0]
    W[2] = A[2]
    solveMatricies(W)
 elif A[2][0] != 0: 
    Z[0] = A[2]
    Z[1] = A[1]
    Z[2] = A[0]
    solveMatricies(Z)
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation, it's critical for Python.

Comment: Could you please indent the code? It is hard to understand what exactly the program does and where an error could exists. Also, for what input you observe errors?
What does solve a matrix refer to?

Comment: Sorry about that. Is that better?

Comment: You're intuition is probably true. Define your array to contain floats if you want to do divisions with it: `A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,-1,-1,0],[4,-3,1,5]], dtype=float)` But can't tell without knowing what's the exact problem you are facing: [ask].

Comment: "but often fails" is not a very useful description. If you're getting a wrong output, please show how it's wrong. If you're getting an error, please include the full error traceback, as that will include detail on what's actually wrong

Comment: @Julien thank you so much! That fixed my problem. I really appreciate your help, man.

Comment: @dbc if it helps closing the unanswered pile... :)

Answer (score 1):

You're intuition is probably true. Define your array to contain floats if you want to do divisions with it: `A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,-1,-1,0],[4,-3,1,5]], dtype=float)`